# "Name" folder appears in the top of every finder window

Tags: macos, finder

I am running Mountain Lion and notice occasionally a weird thing happening in the finder. I will be navigating through folders and notice that at the top of each folder that there is a folder called "Name". I can't click into that folder and there really isn't a folder of that name that should exist.

I've particularly noticed it when using the column view (not sure what else to call it the view where you see each folder in a column as you navigate through them). It only happens intermittently. Has anyone ever seen this or have an idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: Mine has always been set to "None" and I still have the problem of the folder "Name" appearing at the top of each finder window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this, can't reproduce it, but it's a glitch in Finder's Arrange By options, and can be fixed by leaving Arrange set to None.

Comment: Interesting, I did likely have the sort order to be by "Name". It's mostly annoying when it happens, and also one of those moments that makes me wonder if something more is going wrong. Good to know it's just a bug with an easy fix (or that can just be ignored).